# Retrieving all enums in the package

Tags: java

I have a package that contains enums, example:

```
//File SomeEnum.java:
package com.myenums;

public enum SomeEnum {
    SomeValue1,
    SomeValue2;
}

//File SomeEnum2.java:
package com.myenums;

public enum SomeEnum2 {
    SomeValue1,
    SomeValue2;
}
```

In another package (that referencing com.myenums), I want to retrieve with reflection all available enums in com.myenums package.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: @user7294900 I removed the dupe link you supplied. That was unrelated to this question.

Comment: what  dupe link? I didn't supplied any links

Comment: eddyuk, the comment was addressed to user7294900, who originally linked to a duplicate.

Comment: sorry, I see now